# Retrieving multisite blog IDs, somehow failing to foreach them properly

Tags: multisite, wpdb

Working on a directory listing and have cobbled together the shortest query I can. It appears to return the listing ok (I think) but the foreach is somehow failing to process the array properly. Can anyone give me a tip on what I'm doing wrong?

```
global $wpdb; 
$site_blog_ids = array($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs     where blog_id > 1"))); // get all subsite blog ids

print_r( $site_blog_ids ); // checkem - output is "Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 5 ) ) ) "

foreach( $site_blog_ids as $site_blog_id ) { //iterate through the ids
print_r( "siteid ".$site_blog_id ); // checkem - this just outputs "array array" ??
```

The blog IDs aren't coming through the foreach properly somehow, it's just outputting "array array" whereas it should show the list of blog IDs. Does this look like a problem with the $site_blog_ids array or did I mess something else up?

Thanks for any help! David

V.2 per MBoynes' help. Fixed the double array because wpdb already outputs an array. But it's still not working at the foreach to ouput the $site_blog_id, and changing to  "$site_blog_ids[0] AS $site_blog_id" only outputs the first one in the array and then stops.

```
global $wpdb; 
$site_blog_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs where     blog_id > 1")); // get all subsite blog ids

print_r( $site_blog_ids ); // checkem - output is "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 5 ) ) "

foreach( $site_blog_ids AS $site_blog_id ) { //iterate through the ids
print_r( "siteid= ".$site_blog_id."</br>" ); // checkem - this shows no blog ids output at all ??
```

v.3 Working version for posterity
    global $wpdb; 
    $site_blog_ids = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs where     blog_id > 1")); // get all subsite blog ids

```
print_r( $site_blog_ids ); // checkem - output is "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 5 ) ) "

foreach( $site_blog_ids AS $site_blog_id ) { //iterate through the ids
print_r( "siteid= ".$site_blog_id->blog_id."</br>" ); // checkem - anything in the loop that needs the blog ID value must pull it with the ->blog_id key.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `$site_blog_ids` to be an array of arrays. In that case, you'd want to do `foreach ($site_blog_ids[0] as...`

Comment: hmm ok I gotcha, wpdb already returns array. I fixed that and now the output is "Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 2 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 3 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [blog_id] => 5 ) )" so that looks good.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Working now?

Comment: No sadly, still not getting anything for $site_blog_id, and adding [0] only outputs the first one in the array and doesn't do the rest.

Comment: OK, you're close! Now you want to do `$site_blog_id->blog_id` in your print_r and you'll be golden.

Comment: no the print_r's are just to check the output to see what's failing, sorry for the confusion. I've fined it down to the "$site_blog_ids =  " because "print_r($wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT blog_id FROM wp_blogs where blog_id > 1")));" outputs the array just fine, but $site_blog_ids doesn't show anything on print_r. I don't understand at all, there's tons of examples on wpdb and they all look like this.

Comment: Disregard that last, couldn't edit it because we're on an arbitrary 5 min time. TY Stackexchange. Adding ."</br>" to the print_r($site_blog_ids) killed the output somehow, that part is working fine. I am still stuck on why $site_blog_id is empty after the foreach ($site_blog_ids AS $site_blog_id). That's where the problem is.

Comment: Did you try changing `$site_blog_id` to `$site_blog_id->blog_id` like I suggested?

Comment: Yes, it was one of the first things I tried. foreach( $site_blog_ids as $site_blog_id->blog_id ) doesn't change the results at all, $site_blog_id still print_r's as empty within the foreach loop.

Comment: No, like I said, in the `print_r`. Here: https://gist.github.com/1835968

Comment: Matt, if you'll look above, you'll see that the print_r's are just to check the output. They have no purpose other than that.

Comment: That isn't lost on me. It doesn't change the fact that you're doing it wrong. Copy the code in the link I sent and all will be well.

Comment: Oh the LINK. Sorry, I missed that. I'll give it a try and see if I can make it work with the loop code.

Comment: Yup, that works! Thank you Matt! I appreciate the help.